# Unsuccessful DNS request via VPN

Tags: vpn, dns

I want to get into a network via VPN to a server. The VPN gives me a 192.168.101.x IP; the normal IP leases in the network are 192.168.100.x range.

I can access the server via IP but not over FQDN. I also can't connect to any other server in the network via FQDN.

When I am on the network via the (W)LAN, the connection with FQDN succeeds.

DNS entries are made as forward-lookup zones.

Any ideas on how I can access servers via their FQDN?

Comment: What VPN technology and what platforms (on VPN client/server) do you use?

Comment: The VPN an DNS Server are Server 2003. It's the normal Microsoft VPN technology over pptp. The clients are Windows xp, vista and 7.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to manually add the DNS info in the TCP/IP Propersties of the VPN connection.
we had a similar issue with our VPN setup though we were testing a few things and did not have many computers..
hopefully it helps or gives some idea.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the Problem with this is, that there are a lot of people who use this VPN for work. And i am not able to do that at every bodys computer ;)

Comment: Yes thats true managing multiple computers this way is crazy.
as asked by ecdsa what VPN platform are you using, there has to be a DNS option to setup in there.

Comment: Hey, i only use the regular VPN from Microsoft. I double checked it and found nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you're not connected to your local network (LAN) DNS servers that you use do not know the machine you are trying to access. So you use the internet connection of your local network when you connect to VPN, so you go through the proxy or VPN so that you add an entry in your host file (windows) with your machine's name and address ip local. You will then be able to resolve the name of the machine even when connect vpn.

By cons, if its IP address changes and you change your HOST file, you will need to update this one.

windows is his location. c: \ windows \ system32 \ drivers \ etc \ host

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But like the post of user205352 it is no solution, because there are far to many clients that use vpn and i can't change this in every file in each of them.